# How do I solve the Rustlings exercise "move_semantics3.rs"?

Tags: rust

I am doing the [Rustlings exercises](https://github.com/rustlings/rustlings) and there is an exercise "move_semantics3.rs":

```
// move_semantics3.rs
// Make me compile without adding new lines-- just changing existing lines!
// (no lines with multiple semicolons necessary!)
// Scroll down for hints :)

pub fn main() {
    let vec0 = Vec::new();

    let mut vec1 = fill_vec(vec0);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);

    vec1.push(88);

    println!("{} has length {} content `{:?}`", "vec1", vec1.len(), vec1);

}

fn fill_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    vec.push(22);
    vec.push(44);
    vec.push(66);

    vec
}
```

The hint says:

> The difference between this one and the previous ones is that the
>   first line of `fn fill_vec` that had `let mut vec = vec;` is no longer
>   there. You can, instead of adding that line back, add `mut` in one
>   place that will change an existing binding to be a mutable binding
>   instead of an immutable one :)

I have no idea how to correct this code by adding only one `mut`.

Comment: Simply change `fn fill_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {` to `fn fill_vec(mut vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {` , because mutability can change on move.

Answer (score 14):

If you copy/paste the code into the playground, the compiler complains:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable argument `vec` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
19 | fn fill_vec(vec: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32> {
   |             --- consider changing this to `mut vec`
20 |     vec.push(22);
   |     ^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

The compiler says everything: you must replace `vec` with `mut vec` because by default in Rust variable are not mutable.

Comment: @SikaiYao Please don't add "thanks" as comments. [Upvoting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and accepting answers is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: As a beginner I think this is tricky. The original vec0 is immutable. When call fill_vec() we borrow vec0 as mutable. I think this means a shallow copy is made on the stack and the copy is mutable. The original vec0 has lost the binding and can't see any changes. Am I correct? Is this a contrived example or is it something you might see in real code?

Comment: @user1879313 This part of Rust is tricky. The difference between mutable and immutable REFERENCES has a real semantic meaning. A reference also means something specific in memory (the data isn't copied). When there is no reference involved, the lack of `mut` is only a convenient way to change not the data by accident. It's not an inherent property of the data. Also, the (lack of) `mut` says nothing about what happens in memory.

Comment: hey @user1879313, where can I read about this specific topic?

"the lack of mut says nothing about what happens in memory"

Comment: @pablete I only meant that about a non-reference mut.